# Why it cant create the child window?

Tags: c++, winapi, childwindow

Can anyone tell me why the child window cannot be created?
I'm using the forgers win32api guide but I cannot figure out what is the problem.

When the program starts running I have all of the controls, but when I click on the 'new' menuitem I get the error message. This is right after the winmain.

Other things like menuitems, the tool and status bars, opening or saving files works.

```
**HWND CreateNewMDIChild(HWND hMDIClient)
{
    MDICREATESTRUCT mcs;
    HWND hChild;
    mcs.szTitle = "[Untitled]";
    mcs.szClass = g_szChildClassName;
    mcs.hOwner  = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    mcs.x = mcs.cx = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    mcs.y = mcs.cy = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    mcs.style = MDIS_ALLCHILDSTYLES;
    hChild = (HWND)SendMessage(hMDIClient, WM_MDICREATE, 0, (LONG)&mcs);

    if(!hChild)
    {
        MessageBox(hMDIClient, "MDI Child creation failed.", "Oh Oh...",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    }
    return hChild;

}**
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or remove the code of less/no interest.

Comment: how about look - are your windows procedure(of g_szChildClassName) called at all? how about GetLastError() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an unfortunate bug in the [sample code](http://winprog.org/tutorial/app_four.html), that prevents it from running on 64-bit Windows. The final parameter to [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) is of type `LPARAM` (an alias for `LONG_PTR`). Casting it to `LONG` truncates it to 4 bytes, not quite sufficient for a 64-bit pointer (see [Data Type Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)).

Change the following line

```
hChild = (HWND)SendMessage(hMDIClient, WM_MDICREATE, 0, (LONG)&mcs);
```

to

```
hChild = (HWND)SendMessage(hMDIClient, WM_MDICREATE, 0, (LPARAM)&mcs);
```

and the code should run as expected.

Comment: I've made the change but it does not working. I've copypasted the code from the sample file and it works but still don't know how...thanks anyway.